# Magento2 insertListing inside fieldset

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, tabs

I'm trying to insert a listing (grid) inside my edit form fieldset.

```
<fieldset name="printingtable_colors_one" sortOrder="100">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>false</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Kleuren 1</label>
    </settings>
    <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array"><item name="autoRender" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">{{name of grid}}</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

This is what i have now. But nothing is showing.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid.printing_printingtable_grid_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid.printing_printingtable_grid_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Data</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/costs/add</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="sample_data_grid_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PrintingTableGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">spd_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">spd_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">sqd_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">sample_data_grid</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid.printing_printingtable_grid.sample_data_grid_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid.printing_printingtable_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">printing_printingtable_grid.printing_printingtable_grid.printing_printingtable_grid_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>

<columns name="printing_printingtable_grid_columns">

    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">spd_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="spd_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Data ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="title">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Druktabel</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Shirtsbedrukken\PrintingTable\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\PrintingTableActions" sortOrder="200">
        <settings>
            <indexField>spd_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>

</columns>
```

If i paste this in then it doesn't load my data. But i know this isn't the way to go either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<insertListing name="testListingInsert">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">{{ name of configured Listing Ui Component }}</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</insertListing>
```