# how to call a grid file in form.xml in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

Hello everyone I want to call the grid file which is located below path

> Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products in form.xml

Who to write the class for it I have written like this item `name="class" xsi:type="string"Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products</item>`

But no output is coming.

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/204354/59216